# Outlook : Move only read mails to a folder

Tags: delphi, outlook

To move all mails in Outlook I use the following code:

```
var
  App, NS, Inbox, Items, OtherFolder, Item: OleVariant;
  i: Integer;
begin
  App := CreateOleObject('Outlook.Application');
  NS := App.GetNamespace('MAPI');
  NS.Logon;

  Inbox := NS.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox);    
  OtherFolder := Inbox.Parent.Folders('Eléments supprimés');

  Items := Inbox.Items;
  for i := Items.Count downto 1 do
  begin
    Item := Items.Item(i);
    Item.Move(OtherFolder);
  end;
end.
```

Is there a way to move only **all read** mails to the folder?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simple answer is to use `Item.UnRead` to determine whether the item has been read, however:

1. Not all items in a folder are necessarily instances of [`MailItem`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.mailitem) that supports the `UnRead` property. You're using [late binding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Late_binding) to automate MS Outlook and the code will crash if you try to access `UnRead` property on an item that doesn't support it.
2. There are more effective ways to do it.

To demonstrate the options let's first move away from late binding which makes things somewhat complicated and slower. Add unit `Outlook2010` to your uses clause. The source code of the unit is located in OCX\Servers subfolder of RAD Studio installation location. The skeleton of code to process mail items using early binding could then look like this:

```
uses
  System.SysUtils, System.Variants, Outlook2010;

var
  App: OutlookApplication;
  InboxFolder, OtherFolder: Folder;
begin
  App := CoOutlookApplication.Create;
  App.Session.Logon(EmptyParam, EmptyParam, EmptyParam, EmptyParam);
  InboxFolder := App.Session.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox);
  OtherFolder := (InboxFolder.Parent as Folder).Folders.Item('Eléments supprimés');
  ProcessFolder(InboxFolder, procedure(const Item: MailItem)
  begin
    Item.Move(OtherFolder);
  end);
end.
```

The naïve implementation of `ProcessFolder` would be:

```
type
  TMailItemProc = reference to procedure(const Item: MailItem);

procedure ProcessFolder(const AFolder: Folder; MailItemProc: TMailItemProc);
var
  ItemsToProcess: Items;
  Item: MailItem;
  Index: Integer;
begin
  ItemsToProcess := AFolder.Items;
  for Index := ItemsToProcess.Count downto 1 do
    if Supports(ItemsToProcess.Item(Index), MailItem, Item) and (not Item.UnRead) then
      MailItemProc(Item);
end;
```

This approach sucks as it has to go through each item in the folder and check its `UnRead` status. This can cause performance issues when the number of items in the folder is high. But we can do better. Let Outlook do the hard work. And there are multiple ways to do it. The following snippets were inspired by article [How to get unread mail in Outlook](https://www.add-in-express.com/creating-addins-blog/2015/01/29/get-unread-mail-outlook/).

Using [`Items.Restrict`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.items.restrict) method:

```
procedure ProcessFolder(const AFolder: Folder; MailItemProc: TMailItemProc);
var
  ItemsToProcess: Items;
  Item: MailItem;
  Index: Integer;
begin
  ItemsToProcess := AFolder.Items.Restrict('[UnRead]=false');
  for Index := ItemsToProcess.Count downto 1 do
    if Supports(ItemsToProcess.Item(Index), MailItem, Item) then
      MailItemProc(Item);
end;
```

Using [`Items.Find`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.items.find) and [`Items.FindNext`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.items.findnext) methods:

```
procedure ProcessFolder(const AFolder: Folder; MailItemProc: TMailItemProc);
var
  ItemsToProcess: Items;
  FoundItem: IDispatch;
  Item: MailItem;
begin
  ItemsToProcess := AFolder.Items;
  FoundItem := ItemsToProcess.Find('[UnRead]=false');
  while Assigned(FoundItem) do
  begin
    if Supports(FoundItem, MailItem, Item) then
      MailItemProc(Item);
    FoundItem := ItemsToProcess.FindNext;
  end;
end;
```

Using [`Folders.GetTable`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.folder.gettable) method:

```
procedure ProcessFolder(const AFolder: Folder; MailItemProc: TMailItemProc);
var
  Session: NameSpace;
  Table: OutlookTable;
  LRow: Row;
  FoundItem: IDispatch;
  Item: MailItem;
begin
  Session := AFolder.Session;
  Table := AFolder.GetTable('[UnRead]=false', EmptyParam);
  while not Table.EndOfTable do
  begin
    LRow := Table.GetNextRow;
    FoundItem := Session.GetItemFromID(VarToStr(LRow.Item('EntryId')), EmptyParam);
    if Supports(FoundItem, MailItem, Item) then
      MailItemProc(Item);
  end;
end;
```

Comment: Thank you @Peter for this nice detailed explanation. When executing the code, a window appears telling me to select the Outlook profile and right after that, I get an error message that says:
"Operation failed. Cannot find an Object"

Comment: @Amélie See [Turn Outlook profile prompt on or off](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/turn-outlook-profile-prompt-on-or-off-b6f08321-51ec-4c1d-8c25-3e26ea475d25). As for the error - what line causes the exception? Try debugging.

Comment: line causes the exception :         OtherFolder := (InboxFolder.Parent as Folder).Folders.Item('Eléments supprimés');

Comment: @Amélie: That means the folder with that name does not exist within specified parent folder. Please inspect `(InboxFolder.Parent as Folder).Folders` collection to see what's wrong and adapt it to your needs.

Comment: :You are right! The name of the folder is in French and in this language, some words are the same when you start with a capital letter: example: "Éléments supprimés" is "Elements supprimés"

Comment: This is the first letter that triggered this error.
Thank you very much for your precious help.

Comment: Is there a way please to not display the Outlook window which asks us to choose the name of the Outlook Profile?

Comment: @Amélie See the link in my first comment. There's a user setting for that.

Comment: Thanks Peter for your help !!